# Converting List to String - Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

Really basic question, but I am trying to convert what I think is a list into a string, but it's not working.

I have a dataframe like:

```
<OUT> merged
ID      Tags
1     [architecture]
2     [people, loss, chocolate]
3     [rest, exif, castle]
```

I want to remove the `'[]' and ','`. I have tried but to no avail:

```
' '.join(str(i) for i in merged['Tags'])
```

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: ' '.join(x), merged['tags']))`. [EDIT] I think you can just go with @BENY 's answer, seems like you expect that as the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
merged['new'] = merged['Tags'].str.join(' ')
```